# C# Combine list of arrays with count difference

Tags: c#, math, combiners

I'm working on a music application that reads lilypond and midi-files.
Both filetypes needs to be turned into our own storage.

For lilypond you need to read repeat's and their alternatives.
There can however be difference in counting.
If there are three repeatings but two alternatives the first two repeatings get the first alternative and the third alternative gets the last alternative.

Due to re-use being starting at front i don't know how to do it.
My current code looks like this, so the only part missing is combining the repeatList and the altList.

I was hoping there is a math solution for this because flipping the arrays would be tragical for the preformance.

```
    private List<Note> readRepeat(List<string> repeat, List<string> alt, int repeatCount)
    {
        List<Note> noteList     = new List<Note>();
        List<Note> repeatList   = new List<Note>();
        List<List<Note>> altList      = new List<List<Note>>();

        foreach (string line in repeat)
        {
            repeatList.AddRange(readNoteLine(line));
        }

        foreach (string line in alt)
        {
            altList.Add(readNoteLine(line));
        }

        while (repeatCount > 0)
        {
            List<Note> toAdd = repeatList.ToList(); // Clone the list, to destroy the reference

            if (altList.Count() != 0)
            {
                // logic to add the right alt
            }

            noteList.AddRange(toAdd);

            repeatCount--;
        }

        return noteList;
    }
```

In the above code the two lists get populated with the notes.
Their function is as follow:
RepeatList: The basic list of notes that gets played x times
AltList: The list of possibilities to be added to the repeat list.

Some example I/O

- RepeatCount = 4
- AltList.Count() = 3

---

- Repeat 1 gets: Alt 1
- Repeat 2 gets: Alt 1
- Repeat 3 gets: Alt 2
- Repeat 4 gets: Alt 3

Example in visual style

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: what are you actually doing here? you are adding items into 2 lists that are only in the scope of the function and returning a third list that is never populated with data

Comment: Could you provide some data samples and the expected output?

Comment: @GiladGreen I think he wants us to fill the blanks. But I don't understand the requirement. Sample input/output will be necessary.

Comment: It looks like you need to create a class object instead of creating three different objects (noteList, repeatList, altList).

Comment: @GiladGreen Patrice was right, at this moment i got no clue to combine the right repeat to the right alt. I added explanation for my code and I/O information and also applied a bug fix. Hope this helps. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you have `RepeatCount = 5` and `AltList.Count() = 3`? Vice versa, `RepeatCount = 3` and `AltList.Count() = 5`? What if `AltList` is empty? Is it an error? What if `RepeatCount = 0` shall we *do nothing* or *throw exception*?

Comment: @Multi-Cab - it will be very helpful if you type an exact example of data in the 2 lists and the output at the end together with the explanation

Comment: @GiladGreen not sure how to explain anymore, i added the screens of lilypond input output hopes that helps. the repeat start at the tick line followed by two dots, and each numbered block is an alternative numbered with the occurance.
@ DmitryBychenko empty alt list add nothing to the repeatList. if repeatCount is 5 and altList 3, the first 3 repeat contains Alt 1. If the repeat count is 3 and altList 5, the alt will be the same as the repeat, so alt 4 and 5 do nothing.

Comment: You say *"I was hoping there is a math solution for this because flipping the arrays would be tragical for the preformance."* So I assume you have a working solution with array flipping and bad performance?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, here is some possible way to implement the logic part (basically you just have to maintain a cursor on the appropriate alternative). This is in place of your `while` loop.

```
int currentAlt = 0;
for (int currentRepeat = 0; currentRepeat < repeatCount; currentRepeat++)
{
  noteList.AddRange(repeatList);
  noteList.AddRange(altList[currentAlt]);
  if (currentRepeat >= repeatCount - altList.Count)
  {
    currentAlt++;
  }
}
```